# How to show message dialog on Background task in windows phone 10 UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, background-task

I have the background task, and I want to show a message dialog in this background task in some situations like below.

```cs
public sealed class TestTask : IBackgroundTask
{
   public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
   {
      dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;  // -> Crash this line
   }
}
```

As you can see from [Problems with show dialog on Background task in windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25684587/1539100) when I trying to access the UI thread from background task I want to use `CoreDispatcher`.
But when I want to use `CoreDispatcher` in UWP background task, `CoreWindows.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher` is null in constructor and run method, and I get null pointer exception with below message

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Is something has changed in windows phone 10 (UWP) from Windows phone 8.1?

Comment: You have no window when you are running on the background task, hence name BackgroundTask... Please read documentation...

Comment: @Barptad Ok, so how to show message dialog in background task?

Comment: @Barptad It is required in some case to show some message to users when some event occur in background task.

Comment: Show toast... background tasks are intended for long running actions not for user interactions...

Comment: @Barptad toast does not have any button to get some response from user, but MessageDialog has UICommand that can be used for get some response from user. I need something like this.

Comment: What is ITNOA...?

Comment: @CodyGray [ITNOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala). Going back to the original question: Windows 10 adds [interactive toasts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10/).

Comment: Why down vote this question? Is there any problem in question that cause to down vote? When problems are not told how a better question to be asked in the future?

Comment: @RaymondChen very thx to reply this question, but is there any way to force end user to could not skip toast. in another word I want to force end user to answer the popup question anyway.

Comment: That would be a denial of service. E.g. ransomware could just keep displaying unskippable toasts until you pay the money.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up this question, based on the comments here are your options.

1. If you want to have a background task which needs to show information with additional actions to take upon completion use [interactive toasts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10/).
2. If this user interaction action is critical use modals in the actual app and look at in process [background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks), however I see no reason why the need for background task at that point.

If none of the above options suits you it's time to reconsider your current scenario...